# Word advancing in letters each new line

Tags: java

- I want the user to type in a string.
- The console output should have string.length lines (plus the line where the user inputs the string).
- The first line should output the first symbol of the string (string.length) times.
- The second line should output the first symbol of the string and then repeat the second symbol (string.length - 1) times, and so on.

Here is an example of what I want the console output the be with the word "**example**".

```
What will your word be?: example

eeeeeee    
exxxxxx    
exaaaaa    
exammmm    
examppp    
exampll    
example
```

I have no idea where to start with this one. I'd appreciate any help.

**Edit**

Sorry for being so unclear and not providing any code. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class muster{
    public static void main(String s[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What will your string be?");
        String word=sc.next();
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i+1));

    }

}
```

This will read the users input and print the word starting from the first letter with a new letter in each new line. What I still need is that the code repeats the letters for as long as the rest of word.length is.

Comment: Did you already try anything yourself?

Comment: Start by making some code attempt, then narrow down the question to where things are still unclear. At SO, you cannot expect to simply be given a solution. We're happy to answer questions but need to see some research effort/attempt.

Comment: Please try it out yourself and ask here if you face any issue in your solution.

Comment: Break the problem down into small steps -- get user input, get length of input, create loop to print "x" lines, consider using an *inner* loop to help figure out what letters to print on each line.... and then try to solve each small step, one at a time.

Comment: No idea where to start?  How about writing a class with a `main` method?  If you’ve been given this assignment, surely you know how to write the code for the first bullet point, at least.  Are you familiar with loops?  Are you familiar with the `substring` method of String?  Unless you provide your code attempt, we can’t write an answer that addresses your knowledge level.

Comment: I edited the topic. Sorry for not providing any code in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got very close. You already had the idea to print the substring from 0 to `i`. Then you just need an inner loop that starts at `i+1` and loops until `word.length` and print out the char at `i`. Also you need to use `System.out.print()` so that they will be on the same line:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What will your string be?");
String word=sc.next();
for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) {
    System.out.print(word.substring(0,i+1));
    for(int j = i+1; j < word.length(); j++) {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

***Output:***

```
What will your string be?
example
eeeeeee
exxxxxx
exaaaaa
exammmm
examppp
exampll
example
```